# PHP + Calling SOAP API

Tags: php, soap

I am working with SOAP API first time, and I am trying to get response from below function, 
Function Name is : getProducts()

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <ser:GetProducts>
     <product_references>
        <product_reference>REF1</product_reference>
        <product_reference>REF2</product_reference>
     </product_references>
     <get_data/>
     <file_type>xml</file_type>
     <limit/>
     <offset/>
  </ser:GetProducts>
```

This is how I am trying to call this function (Below):

```
  $param[] = new \SoapVar('<get_data  xsi:nil="'.$auto_update.'" />', XSD_ANYXML);

  $param[] = new \SoapVar('xml', XSD_STRING, "file_type ", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

    $param[] = new \SoapVar('SB/EIF/WDS/EMGRN/NAT', XSD_STRING, "product_reference", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");


  $result = $this->request('GetProducts', $param);
```

There is another function I have "GetNewOrders"

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:GetNewOrders>
  <auto_update xsi:nil="true"/>
  <file_type xsi:nil="true"/>
</ns1:GetNewOrders>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I am successfully able to get response from above function by using below code

```
 $param = new \SoapVar('<auto_update xsi:nil="'.$auto_update.'" />', XSD_ANYXML);

    $result = $this->request('GetNewOrders', $param);
```

I want to know How could I pass parameters or in which syntax to get products. Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have a WSDL for your web service?

Comment: @SergioRinaudo I am using "https://example.com/api/soap/wsdl/5" for web services